# Unicode and `url-unhex-string` and something like \345\205\266\344\273\226

Tags: character-encoding, unicode, url

I need to use Emacs built-in `url.el` `url-unhex-string` to decode uri (e.g. `/%E5%85%B6%E4%BB%96/other`)

It works, but all non-ascii (I guess it should be Unicode) characters are all converted into integers with backslashes (e.g. `/\345\205\266\344\273\226/other`

Can I encode these integers back to correct characters? Emacs built-in function is prefered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found solution: use `decode-coding-string`:

```
(url-unhex-string "/%E5%85%B6%E4%BB%96/other") 
;; => "/\345\205\266\344\273\226/other"
(decode-coding-string (url-unhex-string "/%E5%85%B6%E4%BB%96/other") 'utf-8) 
;; => "/其他/other"
```